# understanding dependency relationship in UML component diagram

Tags: uml, component-diagram

I'm struggling at understanding UML component diagram.

I've just been through the "assembly connectors" and here's what I (think I) understood:

- the circle represents an interface, which I understand as a set of functions that a component can offer to the others.
- the half-circle... well, don't know how to call it, but it says something like "there's some  functions I need in order to operate correctly". In the image, I guess that an order must have access to functions that return details of the Customer (e.g: methods `GetName()`, `GetAddress()`, etc.), that's why it has the assembly connection with the `Customer Details` interface, provided by Customer.

My question is: why is there a dependency relationship arrow from the interface which Account provides (`AccountDetails`) and the interface which Order requires (`Payment`)?

The [link of this image](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorials/uml2/component-diagram.html) doesn't explain it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly connector (two shown on top) is a kind of provisional concept. You know that there should be an interface used instead, but have not yet made up the details. This is a connector which looks like socket/lollipop. But it's a connector.

The separate lollipop/socket are concrete interface uses. These are real elements. The interface itself is not actually shown (you will have a separate diagram showing the details). But to make clear that the depending interface is related to the providing one you draw a dependency.

Simply spoken, the above is something in the middle of a design phase. Finally all assemblies should be replaced by provided/required interfaces.

Comment: Still confused. Why would one need a dependency relationship between `Account` and `Order` and not between `Customer` and `Order`, since it seems `Order` need both of them?

Comment: it makes sense, but are you sure this dependency is only there because this image is a incomplete prototype?

Comment: @Daniel look at the norm ( https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF), second § on the top of page 210, and Fig 11.46 page 214 explained at end of page 213

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. As bruno points out you can look into the UML specs. The standard has a couple of flaws (luckily not too many). So I think it's unlucky to have the assembly connector look exactly like a socket/lollipop pair. Just leads to confusion, but it's that way currently.